# CSS element appears below current line. How to fix?

Tags: html, css

I am making some HTML elements as follows:

```css
.rc-CN-Item {
  height: 4em;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}

.rc-CN-ItemFlagVisible {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 160, 240);
  display: inline-block;
}

.rc-CN-ItemTextbox {
  margin-left: 10%;
  /* same as Flag width*/
  width: 90%;
  /* 100 - Flag width*/
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(100, 160, 240);
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  letter-spacing: .125em;
}
```

```html
<!--  Block-->
<div class="rc-CN-Block">
  <!--  Item  -->
  <div class="rc-CN-Item">
    <!--  Flag  -->
    <div class="rc-CN-ItemFlagVisible">
    </div>
    <!--  Textbox  -->
    <div class="rc-CN-ItemTextbox">Home
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It does not come out as intended, with the textbox getting pushed to the next line as can be seen here:

[image: img]

What went wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try adding `float: left; ` to your divs

Comment: Thanks @Alex.  Found my solution below.

Comment: both width + margin (90% + 10% + 10%) > 100%. You don't need the margin-left and you need to consider the whitespace between inline block

Comment: @TemaniAfif, this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sidenav_fixed) tells me that the second element's left margin has to be the width of the first element.  It worked for me for another thing, but not quite sure how it no longer this time.

Comment: in that example the first element is fixed so its removed from the normal flow

Answer (score 2):

> Use `display: flex` to make inline all child elements

```css
.rc-CN-Item
{
    height: 4em;
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    display: flex;
}
.rc-CN-ItemFlagVisible
{
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 160, 240);
    display: inline-block;
}
.rc-CN-ItemTextbox
{    
    margin-left: 10%;  /* same as Flag width*/
    width: 90%;       /* 100 - Flag width*/
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(100, 160, 240);
    /*margin: 1.25em .625em 2.5em; top, right, bottom, left */
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    letter-spacing: .125em;
}
```

```html
<!--  Block-->
<div class="rc-CN-Block">
    <!--  Item  -->
    <div class="rc-CN-Item">
        <!--  Flag  -->
        <div class="rc-CN-ItemFlagVisible">
        </div>
        <!--  Textbox  -->
        <div class="rc-CN-ItemTextbox">Home
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is good to know.  I can now delete the `inline` specifications in child items.

Answer (score 0):

This line is your issue:

```
margin-left: 10%;  /* same as Flag width
```

Your flag takes 10%, your text margin takes 10%, and your text takes 90%. 110% has to wrap!

Comment: I set it to 0% and it works, but now I have no margin.  This is a bit strange because I have it working elsewhere based on this W3S [guide](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sidenav_fixed). 
 Basically, the margin of the second element is the width of the first element.  What happened in this case?

Comment: The math adds up in this solution. One thing that may be different is inline-block. That means they influence the things around them. Theyre "part of the flow". But if originally the flag was absolute, it was "out of the flow".

Comment: I also have to add `display: flex` in parent item in addition to make it work.  Any idea?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I don't know flex :/ Try asking Sameer Khan about that

Comment: But if you had to change the Item as well, it's possible that making it "width:100%;padding:0;margin:0" would also work instead of flex.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Sameer Khan's solution (adding `display: flex` to parent item) only gets me this:

[image: aa]

Using @Sydney Y's solution only gets me this:

[image: bb]

Combined, I got what I want:

[image: cc]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit ancient approach that works as well.

Use `float: left;` and `box-sizing: border-box;`

```css
.rc-CN-Item {
  height: 4em;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}

.rc-CN-ItemFlagVisible {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 160, 240);
  float: left;
}

.rc-CN-ItemTextbox {
  /* same as Flag width*/
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  /* 100 - Flag width*/
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(100, 160, 240);
  font-family: Arial;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  letter-spacing: .125em;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!--  Block-->
<div class="rc-CN-Block">
  <!--  Item  -->
  <div class="rc-CN-Item">
    <!--  Flag  -->
    <div class="rc-CN-ItemFlagVisible">
    </div>
    <!--  Textbox  -->
    <div class="rc-CN-ItemTextbox">Home
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```